# Play Framework Run Application Issue

Tags: java, frameworks, playframework

I am getting the following error whenever i am trying to run a new Web Application created using [Play](http://www.playframework.org/).

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap

Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Comment: what arguments are passed to the application? anything like this?     -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=64M -XX:MaxPermSize=1000M. If so remove or decrease the values of Xms and -XX:PermSize

Answer (score 25):

In Play framework 2.0.3, `<play framework install dir>\framework\build.bat` script you need to replace the command line argument for the command below

```
java -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M %DEBUG_PARAM% -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Dplay.version="%PLAY_VERSION%" -Dsbt.ivy.home="%~dp0..\repository" -Dplay.home="%~dp0." -Dsbt.boot.properties="file:///%p%sbt/sbt.boot.properties" -jar "%~dp0sbt\sbt-launch.jar" %*
```

Into

```
java -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled %DEBUG_PARAM% -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Dplay.version="%PLAY_VERSION%" -Dsbt.ivy.home="%~dp0..\repository" -Dplay.home="%~dp0." -Dsbt.boot.properties="file:///%p%sbt/sbt.boot.properties" -jar "%~dp0sbt\sbt-launch.jar" %*
```

Comment: still valid for migration from 2.0.x to 2.1

Comment: Why do we need to do so? I mean... one just finishes installing Play, creates a new project, and tries to run it and KABOOM! error... What's wrong? What's the cause of the problem?

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 7 64-bit using version play-2.2.1. The question is why do I still need to do this one year later?

Answer (score 0):

Just downloaded and unzipped 2.2.1 on my Windows 8 computer.

Followed the documentation at Play Framework website, and ended up having the same issue as you. Adjusting the various parameters in the build file didn't do anything, but the:

```
java -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled %DEBUG_PARAM% -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Dplay.version="%PLAY_VERSION%" -Dsbt.ivy.home="%~dp0..\repository" -Dplay.home="%~dp0." -Dsbt.boot.properties="file:///%p%sbt/sbt.boot.properties" -jar "%~dp0sbt\sbt-launch.jar" %*
```

... solved the problem. 
I don't know where other people found this solution, but there's no mentioning of this solution on the Play Framework website. In fact, there's nothing to suggest that anything could go wrong. After all, it's just a file you need to unzip.

It's running now, however it's a little hard to trust a framework that screws up that early on. Seems the authors don't test on anything but Linux.

Answer (score 0):

in 2.3 Play framework :

```
    GO to :
```

C://Play2.3/framework/build.bat and open this file and make these changes.
Replace this line with below line.

java -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M %DEBUG_PARAM% -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Dplay.version="%PLAY_VERSION%" -Dsbt.ivy.home="%~dp0..\repository" -Dplay.home="%~dp0." -Dsbt.boot.properties="file:///%p%sbt/sbt.boot.properties" -jar "%~dp0sbt\sbt-launch.jar" %*

java -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled %DEBUG_PARAM% -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Dplay.version="%PLAY_VERSION%" -Dsbt.ivy.home="%~dp0..\repository" -Dplay.home="%~dp0." -Dsbt.boot.properties="file:///%p%sbt/sbt.boot.properties" -jar "%~dp0sbt\sbt-launch.jar" %*

then type this command on command promt:

```
       C:\Users\k.ashish\Downloads\play-2.2.3\play-2.2.3\yourapp>play

        C:\Users\k.ashish\Downloads\play-2.2.3\play-2.2.3\yourapp>run
```

If you are not able to execute this command then set the play2.3 framework path in Environment variable in windows like java path .