# Playframework :could not execute play command

Tags: playframework

I started to study Play framework but got some incident.
Currently I download Playframework : play_2.0.2

My java environment as below :
JDK : java version "1.7.0_05"
Runtime :javac 1.6.0_22

After setting path to enviroment variable: 
I started create new project by using this step :
C:\play new todolist
C:\cd todolist
C:\todolist>play
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Please guidance with those error message. I need to deploy and play with it.

Rgds,
Gard

Comment: It appears that you don't have enough memory!

Comment: I doubt it, since i have 4096MB installed on and by looking using Resource Monitor i have 1232MB available.

Comment: To help another new comers in playframework,
I do some changes on [play-dir]/framework/build file
change by lowering limit to be as below :
  -Xms128m -Xmx256m 
it solve the problem.

Comment: Someone had same problem and had been fixed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071950/play-framework-run-application-issue)